# How can I set form values with Ajax?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I want to set the value of a textfield based upon the selection of a field above. You can choose a template and the textfield would have it as a value.

This is the select field used to select the template with the ajax call

```
// Template Select field
$form['template'] = [
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => $this->t('Template'),
'#options' => $event_templates_select,
'#required' => TRUE,
'#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::changeOutputValue',
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
    element.
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'edit-output',
        'progress' =>[
            'type' => 'throbber',
            'message' => $this->t('Updating e-mail template'),
        ],
    ]
];
```

This is the textfield that I want to display the value. It's in a ckeditor.

```
// Textarea field
$form['output'] = [
'#type' => 'text_format',
'#format' => 'full_html',
'#required' => TRUE,
'#disabled' => FALSE,
'#value' => 'hallo',
'#prefix' => '<div id="edit-output" class="acceptform__output">',
'#suffix' => '</div>',
];
```

And finally, the ajax function

```
  public function changeOutputValue(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $selected_option =  $form_state->getValue('template');
    if ($selected_option == 0){
        $output_text = '';
    } else {
        $template = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($selected_option);
        $tempate_content = $template->get('field_template')->getValue();
        $tempate_content = $tempate_content[0]['value'];
        $output_text = $tempate_content;
    }


    $form['output']['#value'] = $output_text;

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    return $response;

  }   
}
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong. I was trying to follow the drupal 8 form api docs but I can't get it to work with a ckeditor field.

The select field contains a number of e-mail templates. Upon selecting one, I want to display the template in the output field with a ckeditor so the user can still make changes if necessary.

I'm using Drupal 8 with a custom module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. First try to rebuild the form without ajax. Build all form elements, also the ones which are added in a later rebuild, in the form build. When this is working add the ajax callback, which then only needs one statement, to return the changed part of the form in a wrapper.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping! The form works fine and I've edited the ajax function but it's still not updating the field value. I'm also not really sure what you mean with a wrapper.

Comment: Returning the entire or part of $form in a div wrapper is the standard ajax pattern, see the examples in [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples).

Answer (score 0):

From the ajax callback, you only need to return the render array containing the data to be inserted into the div you have specified as the callback to your #ajax.

So in the ajax callback you can return this, rather than an AjaxResponse:

```
return $form['output'];
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but only in a textarea. I'm trying to show the output in a ` '#type' => 'text_format '` so that I can use the ckeditor.

Comment: No, it will work for any render array elements, not just textareas. Whatever part of the form render array you return will be rendered and inserted into the element with the ID you've specified as the #ajax wrapper. It doesn't matter what the type of the render array element is.

Answer (score 0):

In case the radio button is **disabled** you can use the prop function instead of click as seen in the example below.

```
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $selector='#process-wrapper .fieldset-wrapper input[name=field_form_gasto_procedimiento][value='.$proc.']'; // A jQuery selector
  $method='prop'; // The name of a jQuery method to invoke.
  $arguments=['checked', true];
  $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand($selector,$method,$arguments));
  return $response;
```